# HTML5 Canvas flashing text?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Does anyone know how to do the following things sequentially on an HTML5 canvas (using javascript).

1. Text appears (I already know how to do this :P)
2. Text flashes several times at one second intervals
3. Text disappears after 5 seconds (or whenever)

The reason I find this so hard to do, is because there is no way to create a pause in a script. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function flashyText() {
    var count = 10,
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            count--;
            if( count%2 == 1) {
                // draw the text
            }
            else {
                // don't draw it (ie. clear it off)
            }
            if( count == 0) clearInterval(timer);
        },1000);
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: I like what I see there! I'll give it a go and see if it works well.

Comment: Just ran into an issue, the whole canvas is cleared every frame. Maybe a JSFiddle of my source would help you come up with something to resolve this. http://jsfiddle.net/4BcV5/

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very experienced with HTML5 Canvas, I prefer to use GameMaker:HTML5 instead.

Comment: Its ok, I just figured out how to overcome the issue anyways. Have a second canvas overlayed on top of the other, that isn't constantly being cleared.